# How to get all tokens from Ethereum Chain

Tags: ethereum

I want to know how to get a list of all existing erc20 tokens in the ethereum blockchain. Because I want to get a list of all coins what a users holds in his wallet.

Comment: I can't think of an api for that, maybe Moralis or Alchemy has one... There's probably a way to scan it one block at a time for new ERC20s but it would take forever.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to write an indexer that can go through each block and filter ERC20 contract deployments. There is an example for something similar (with some handy features like writing progress to a file) in the [web3 documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#example-code).